# Rescaling Sentinel2 data to 8 bit using GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, sentinel-2, resolution

I need to rescale Sentinel2 data (both lvl 1C and 2A) to 8 bit, because of the requirements of a GRASS GIS module (`i.histo.match`) that only works with values from 0:255. All the documentation of Sentinel2 [1C](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-1c/product-formatting) and [2A](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-2a/product-formatting) data products say that the data are encoded at 12bit, but that is not up to date (also this other post pointed this out https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/234044/172030). In fact, if I run `gdalinfo` on my L1C files, it says that it has 15 significant bits:

> Image Structure Metadata: 
> COMPRESSION=JPEG2000 
> NBITS=15

while if I run it on my L2A files (created with Sen2Cor, not downloaded) it omits the "NBITS" field.

> Image Structure Metadata: 
> COMPRESSION=JPEG2000

I don't know how to correctly perform the conversion.

Should I treat the data as formatted in 15 or 16 bits i.e. *DN / 2^15 * 2^8* or *DN / 2^16 * 2^8*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `max=` parameter to `i.histo.match` to retain the full range of values with input rasters like S2 that use 15 bit DN, without any rescaling.

I checked two S2 images (band 8 for two dates), using `r.univar` and found the max values about 16,000. So I ran:

```
micha@RMS:Western Negev$ i.histo.match input=`g.list rast sep=comma pat=b08*` max=18000 --o
```

The resulting histogram-matched rasters showed more or less the same range of values:

```
micha@RMS:Western Negev$ r.univar b08_20210125.match
 100%
total null and non-null cells: 49343168
total null cells: 44910908

Of the non-null cells:
----------------------
n: 4432260
minimum: 11
maximum: 16248
range: 16237
mean: 2356.4
mean of absolute values: 2356.4
standard deviation: 1625.54
variance: 2.64238e+06
variation coefficient: 68.9838 %
sum: 10444197995
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding S2 data as being fully 16-bit will result in "overcompression", as not all the bits within the image are actually used. What you should do is to identify the minimum and maximum values within the raster, and then use those to linearly rescale to a range between 0 and 255.

Basically, that becomes:

```
rescaled_value=round((pixel_value − min_observed) / (max_observed − min_observed)*255)
```

And then just save that as 8-bit data.

Answer (score 1):

Here a script I have written some time ago which rescales to 8 bit and exports into GeoTIFF (or COG):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Markus Neteler, mundialis 2018
# 8bit export of satellite data, e.g. Sentinel-2

#BAND_R=T32ULB_20170314T104011_B04
#BAND_G=T32ULB_20170314T104011_B03
#BAND_B=T32ULB_20170314T104011_B02
BAND_R=mosaik_B08
BAND_G=mosaik_B03
BAND_B=mosaik_B02

# vector
AOI=ireland_aoi1
AOIEXT=gpkg

v.import input=$AOI.$ext out=$AOI

##### 
# rescale to 8bit
for band in $BAND_R $BAND_G $BAND_B ; do
  g.region vector=$AOI align=$band -p
  #eval `r.info $band -r`
  # leave 0 for nodata
  r.rescale input=$band output=${band}_8bit to=1,255
done

i.colors.enhance r=${BAND_R}_8bit g=${BAND_G}_8bit b=${BAND_B}_8bit

# we try to export with color table
i.group group=rgb_8bit input=${BAND_R}_8bit,${BAND_G}_8bit,${BAND_B}_8bit

# separate 8bit band export (optionally, write out COG)
for band in $BAND_R $BAND_G $BAND_B ; do
   r.out.gdal input=${band}_8bit output=${band}_geotiff_8bit.tif type=Byte create="COMPRESS=LZW" nodata=0 -m
done

# combine to RGB GeoTIFF
gdal_merge.py  -separate ${BAND_R}_geotiff_8bit.tif ${BAND_G}_geotiff_8bit.tif ${BAND_B}_geotiff_8bit.tif -o s2_${AOI}_geotiff_8bit.tif -co COMPRESS=LZW

# GeoTIFF -> TIFF (optionally, write out COG)
gdal_translate -co PROFILE=BASELINE -co COMPRESS=LZW  s2_${AOI}_geotiff_8bit.tif s2_${AOI}_8bit.tif

rm -f ${BAND_R}_geotiff_8bit.tif ${BAND_G}_geotiff_8bit.tif ${BAND_B}_geotiff_8bit.tif s2_${AOI}_geotiff_8bit.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a question about GRASS GIS but I ended up on this Q&A looking for how to do this in ArcGIS Pro. I add my answer just in case other ArcGIS Pro users end up here.

@Mikkel gives a great generic answer but I thought there must be a simpler way to do this in ArcGIS Pro and it turns out there is!

1. Load your 16 bit sentinel 2 raster into a map
2. Right click on it in TOC and select Data > Export Raster
3. Select the 8 bit unsigned pixel type and the scale pixel value check box appears, simply tick that on and complete the dialog.

[image: Scale Pixel]